# In plain sight I lie

Tags: riddle

Riddle me this:

> Many have tried me,
>
> And many failed,
>
> Many make me,
>
> And in plain sight I lie,
>
> My secret bound tight, I ask you, what am I?

HINT

> Not lie as in to tell a lie but to lie down or upon

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many have tried me,

> Many people try to answer riddles

And many failed,

> Many people fail at them

Many make me,

> There is a certain website called puzzling.stackexchange.com where people make riddles

And in plain sight I lie,

> Answer is obvious once revealed, making it seem as if in plain sight.

My secret bound tight, I ask you, what am I?

> As a riddle, I never easily give up my answer

Comment: Could you explain why you think that? Answers without explanation are deleted.

Comment: @Deusovi done working on it when you put comment

Comment: Some man say that my english is bad so people feel free to edit my answer its okay haha if any incorrection

Comment: @RahulSrinath Yes, that is correct!

Comment: The answer lies in plain sight in the single tag attached to the question.

Comment: @MOehm But others don't know this :( Shouldn't have pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> A lie

Many have tried me,

> Almost everybody has lied at some point

And many failed,

> There are many times where a lie is not fallen for,

Many make me,

> You can make a lie just as you can try to lie

And in plain sight I lie,

> Lies lie. Not much to explain here.

My secret bound tight, I ask you, what am I?

> The truth is the secret, as a lie will never expose the truth.

Comment: Oh no, I was afraid of this, I hadn't clarified which lie it is. What I had in mind is not this. However, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are:

> a riddle

because:

> many people try but they often fail because it's supposed to be difficult.
>  many make me, like here on stackexchange.
>  in plain sight I lie, my secret bound tight.
>  The answer is hard to find, but it's always in the question.

Comment: This is the same as Rahul Srinath's answer.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This answer duplicates a different one: please read all the current answers before adding your own.

Comment: @MikeM. Im sorry, but it shows up as Anna answered ~23 minutes ago while Rahul ~29 mins ago. Rahul edited ~14 mins ago, but this does not count.

Comment: @MikeM. Hahaha, how silly of me! Im sorry.

Comment: @Fluxenein MikeM. is right, Rahul was first. 29 mins ago is before 23 mins ago. Although Deusovi was wrong, I didn't duplicate Rahuls answer, but I'm not english so it took me a while to type my answer.

Comment: @Anna: Nobody's accusing you of ***copying*** the answer.  We have all been in the situation of thinking of an answer (and maybe typing it), only to discover that somebody else got it in first.  But we suggest that, before posting your answer, you read all the others.  If yours is the same as one or more of the others, don’t post it, unless you’re really contributing something new (like a better explanation, for example).

Comment: @Fluxenein: By the way (FYI), if you hover your mouse over the “29 mins ago” text, it will show you the exact time it happened, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lOZfJ.png).

Comment: @PeregrineRook I was aware of that, but was very tired and screwed up some basic logic. Thanks for reminding anyways, I'll be sure to check that first haha.

Comment: By the timestamps, the other answer was posted first but didn't have the explanation added until after this one.

Comment: Oh wow I would have lost title of write answer

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was posted by @Rahul Srinath. However, here's an alternative reasoning for "Many make me,", other than stated by him:

> The answer is that it is a riddle. Where are you viewing this riddle? On an LCD. Thus, the riddle is made up of many liquid crystals emitting light at you to display this riddle. They are the "many"